# Python and GnuCash: Extract data from GnuCash files

Tags: python, api, matplotlib

I'm looking for information on how to read GnuCash files using python. I have read about this [`python-gnucash`](http://parit.ca/projects/pythongnucash/) which provides Python bindings to the GnuCash library, but it takes a lot of work at the moment (e.g. dependencies, headers, etc.). The instructions are tailored for the Linux environment, and a rather old GnuCash version (2.0.x). I am running GnuCash 2.2.9. Though I can operate the Linux command line, I am running GnuCash on Windows XP.

My main objective is to **read** (no plans to *write* yet) my GnuCash files so that I can create my own visual dynamic reports using `matplotlib` and `wxpython`. I'm not yet in the mood to learn Scheme.

I hope someone can point me to a good start on this. As far as I know about GnuCash and Python, I think someone probably knows solutions of the following types:

1. More recently updated documentation aside from [this one from the GnuCash wiki](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Python_Bindings)
2. Some workaround, like exporting to a certain file format for which there is a more mature Python library that can read it.

You guys might have better suggestions in addition to those mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about the data files?  From there [wiki](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/File), it looks like they are just compressed XML files.  WIth Python, you can decompress them with the [gzip module](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html) and then parse them with any of the [available XML parsers](http://docs.python.org/library/markup.html).

**ElementTree Example**

```
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
>>> xmlStr = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<painting>
<img src="madonna.jpg" alt='Foligno Madonna, by Raphael'/>
<caption>This is Raphael's "Foligno" Madonna, painted in
     <date>1511</date>?<date>1512</date>.
</caption>
</painting>
'''
>>> tree = ET.fromstring(xmlStr)  #use parse or iterparse to read direct from file path
>>> tree.getchildren()
[<Element 'img' at 0x115efc0>, <Element 'caption' at 0x1173090>]
>>> tree.getchildren()[1].text
'This is Raphael\'s "Foligno" Madonna, painted in\n    '
>>> tree.getchildren()[0].get('src')
'madonna.jpg'
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! That looks good for a start. I have managed to decompress it with the `gzip` module. I tried the first XML parser I saw with an example (`Expat`), but unfortunately, I couldn't parse out the tags and contents. Can you recommend which XML parser I should use, or at least get started with?

Comment: @Kit, my favorite in the standard library is cElementTree (http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).  Make sure to use the cElementTree instead of ElementTree (the former is written in C and later is pure python) for extra speed.  See edits above for a little quick start.

Comment: This is great. I'm still quite stumped at dealing with namespaces in the `{URI}tag` format. Anyway, that would be a topic for another question. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I just found out that `lxml.etree` does a better job at [handling namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428792/xml-and-python-get-the-namespaces-declared-in-root-element/3428820#3428820).

Answer (score 8):

I published piecash, a python interface to SQL saved GnuCash books that uses SQLAlchemy as basis (https://github.com/sdementen/piecash).

With it you can easily access all the information contained in a book.

For instance, to iterate over all accounts in the book:

```
from piecash import open_book

# open a book
with open_book("some_book.gnucash", open_if_lock=True) as mybook:
    # iterate over all accounts of the book
    for account in mybook.accounts:
        print(account)
```

or to iterate over all the splits in the "Asset" account:

```
# open the book
with open_book("some_book.gnucash", open_if_lock=True) as mybook:
    # retrieve the account by its fullname
    asset = mybook.accounts(fullname="Asset")
    # iterate over all its splits
    for split in asset.splits:
        print(split)
```

Recent versions also allows to extract the split information directly to pandas DataFrames for easy plotting/analysis with

```
from piecash import open_book

# open a book
with open_book("some_book.gnucash", open_if_lock=True) as mybook:
    # extract all split information to a pandas DataFrame
    df = mybook.splits_df()

    # print for account "Asset" some information on the splits
    print(df.loc[df["account.fullname"] == "Asset",
                 ["transaction.post_date", "value"]])
```

Comment: That is not the basis for a downvote. Consider that the user is new to SO. @sdementen, take note of Jason's comments and provide details/examples of how the data can be extracted using your library.

Comment: So far, this seems to be the only option available on Windows. And a very good one, at that.

Answer (score 6):

GNUCash 2.4 is out.

Can export to SQL so it's very much easier than parsing XML.

Sqlite, MySQL and PostgreSQL are supported (how cool is that!)

Comment: Will you please tell me how to activate `export to sql` function? I can't find it in the menu, only xml export (File->Export->Export Accounts). I'm using Gnucash 2.4.12.

Comment: I'm running gnucash 2.6 as packaged by Ubuntu 14.04.  I didn't see the export to SQL option, but I noticed that the gnucash package recommended libdbd-{mysql,pgsql,sqlite} packages which I didn't have installed.  Adding those made the export options appear in the interface.  So there's a compiled executable with Python templating, and perl data bindings.  Wierd.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libdbd-sqlite3` in Ubuntu to get mysql features in GnuCash 2.6. Then open your book in GnuCash and select "File" -> "Save As ..." and select "mysql" as the data format.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken the sqlite approach in a django app I've written to do a similar thing (although for budgeting).   See https://github.com/evandavey/OpenBudget/blob/master/openbudgetapp/management/commands/gnucash-import.py for the code.

In terms of the data itself, I've used the pandas library to handle its time series nature.

Comment: Might have been useful once, but the link is now broken.

Answer (score 1):

As Chop Suey said, GnuCash 2.4 has its own database format. If you still want to use the XML files, you can use the following script to convert from XML to a database, and then write your reports on that (e.g. gnucashconvert filename.gnucash sqlite3:////home/username/export.sqlite):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import gnucash

def convert_gnucash(src_uri, target_uri):
    """Converts gnucash databases at the given uris from src to target"""
    session = gnucash.Session(src_uri)
    try:
        new_session = gnucash.Session(target_uri, is_new=True)
        try:
            new_session.swap_data(session)
            new_session.save()
        finally:
            new_session.end()
            new_session.destroy()
    finally:
        session.end()
        session.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        src_uri, target_uri = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
        src_uri = ("xml://%s" % os.path.abspath(src_uri) if "://" not in src_uri else src_uri)
        target_uri = ("xml://%s" % os.path.abspath(target_uri) if "://" not in target_uri else target_uri)
        convert_gnucash(src_uri, target_uri)
    else:
        print >>sys.stderr, "Syntax %s src target" % (sys.argv[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

I just published some python code that can read and interpret the sqlite3 file format used in gnucash 2.6 and higher:

https://github.com/MatzeB/pygnucash

Comment: sqlite is an option, only present if the perl data binding libraries are present.