# XML and Python: Get the namespaces declared in root element

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces

How do I access the multiple `xmlns` declarations at the root element of an XML tree? For example:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
data = """<root
             xmlns:one="http://www.first.uri/here/"
             xmlns:two="http://www.second.uri/here/">

          ...all other child elements here...
          </root>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
# I don't know what to do here afterwards
```

I want to get a dictionary similar to this one, or at least some format to make it easier to get the URI and the matching tag

```
{'one':"http://www.first.uri/here/", 'two':"http://www.second.uri/here/"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how this might be done with `xml.etree`, but with [lxml.etree](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) you could do this:

```
import lxml.etree as le
data = """<root
             xmlns:one="http://www.first.uri/here/"
             xmlns:two="http://www.second.uri/here/">

          ...all other child elements here...
          </root>"""

tree = le.XML(data)
print(tree.nsmap)
# {'two': 'http://www.second.uri/here/', 'one': 'http://www.first.uri/here/'}
```